# On HTML script load how to assign a value

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that when a page is loaded it calls an API method as follows:

```
var script = string.Format("API.methods.createUser({0},function (new) {{$('#RegistrationForm').hide();$('#number').html(new.Number)}});",
                            Webservice.GetJavascriptObject(list, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "first name ", name }));
```

On the `$('#number')` it gets me the users account number when the script runs.

I want to assign this account number to the list object so I tried

```
List.Number ="$('#number').html(new.Number);"
```

But literally just assigns what I have in the on the right of the equal sign and not the actual account number.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take the quote marks off that are wrapping the assignment value

Answer (score 2):

Take the quote marks off that are wrapping the assignment value

Change it to this

```
List.Number =$('#number').html();
```

By wrapping it in quote marks, you were assigning it as a string.

Comment: i tried this,but when i add it like that it doesnt like it,it says invalid expression term

Comment: This is a different issue, probably caused by something else in your script. Probably a good idea to ask it as a separate question, and post more of your code.